# npm install grunt-takana fails at node-gyp rebuild

Tags: python, node.js, gruntjs, npm, node-gyp

I am trying to install `grunt-takana` but it one of its prerequisites for Windows, `node-gyp` seems very problematic.

In `cmd`, when I try `npm install grunt-takana` I get following errors after `node-gyp rebuild`:

> nodefsevents.cc
>   ..\nodefsevents.cc(11): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pthread.h
>   ': No such file or directory (...)

and at the end another one:

> Binary is fine; exiting
>   npm ERR! fsevents@0.1.6 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the fsevents@0.1.6 install script.

When I try manual `node-gyp rebuild` in `c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp` I receive a bit more specific error:

> gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_m
>   odules\node-gyp) while trying to load binding.gyp

So far I've installed:
- node v0.10.32
- node-gyp v1.0.2
- Python 2.6 (tried also 2.7.9)
- MS Visual Studio 2013 (Ultimate)
- MS .NET Framework SDK 2.0

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `grunt-takana` is expecting a Unix style threading library (`pthread.h`).  The official `takana` docs do not say Windows is supported:

> Currently, Takana supports OSX, Linux and Sublime Text 2 & 3.

https://github.com/mechio/takana

Comment: I know it's officially not supported, but I've seen it worked for someone: https://github.com/mechio/takana/issues/33